# share sql database across virtual machines on remote desktop

Tags: sql-server, remote-desktop

I am looking to use a SQL database on one VM as the enterprise repository for an application on another VM. Basically, I need to connect the SQL database to the initial virtual machine on the new virtual machine.

Comment: This seems to me more like a system administrator question. Please read [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

Well you can't do this through remote desktop, the protocols are entirely different. However, as far as networking two virtual machines together goes that would really depend on the vendor of your virtualization software.

VMWare workstation allows you to create local private networks, while the free versions of VMWare and Virtualbox both support bridged network functionality where they obtain their own IP address from your local network. The standard passthrough networking functionality will not work correctly since your app server will not know how to reference the database instance.